# Index/Match function output appears out of sync

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am attempting to use index/match in conjunction with an if/and statement that does the following.

If column C = Secondary

AND if column D = Information/Videos

Take value of column B and output it.

This is not what is happening. The only case it is working is for the first occurrence of it. **See the reference sheet and output sheets below**. In the reference sheet, I labeled the rows/values in which should be appearing and labelled the respective row. Then look at the output sheet. The labelled row 1 is correct. However, after that the outputs are not correct or recognizing the rows that should pull over.

Does anyone see what is wrong?

**Formula**

`=IF(AND(Workflow!$C26="Secondary",Workflow!$D26=$B$2),INDEX(Workflow!$B$10:$B$298,MATCH($B$2,Workflow!$D21:$D228,0)),"")`

**Reference sheet**

[image]

**Output sheet**

[image]

**UPDATED**

[image]

Comment: Your return range: `Workflow!$B$10:$B$298` is out of sync with your search range: `Workflow!$D21:$D228`  Match returns the RELATIVE row, not the ACTUAL row to the INDEX.  Make them both ranges start and end on the same row.

Comment: MATCH() in range $D21:$D228 , but INDEX() in range $B$10:$B$298 ? What happens if the range sizes are the same - $D21:$D228 and $B21:$B228 (or $D$10:$D$298 and $B$10:$B$298)?

Comment: @ScottCraner See new photo labeled "UPDATE" above. When I do this to your point `=IF(AND(Workflow!$C15="Secondary",Workflow!$D15=$B$2),INDEX(Workflow!$B10:$B298,MATCH($B$2,Workflow!$D10:$D217,0)),"")`  the range still outputs the incorrect values. Basically what you saw in my initial was I had absolute value on one and dragged down the formula.

Comment: `=IF(AND(Workflow!$C15="Secondary",Workflow!$D15=$B$2),Workflow!$B15,"")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Are you saying that I don't need the index/match function?

Comment: correct.  Just put that in your first cell, assuming row 15 is the first row on the other sheet.  Then copy it down.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks! That did the trick.